# Assigning current path to variable VB.net

Tags: vb.net, variables, filepath

I have an idea here but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
Dim currentPath As String
    If System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "AccountServer.exe") OrElse System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "AccountServer.exe") Then

    End If
```

What I want to do is I want the program to look for AccountServer.exe in current file, if the program did not find it, then it will look at AccountServer/AccountServer.exe.

If it finds the current path of that .exe then it will assign it to currentPath variable.

How will I do this or is it even possible?

Comment: `Path.Combine()` returns the result of combining, not....whatever you are expecting.  Turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some logic to see if the file is present:

```
        Dim currentPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "AccountServer.exe")
        If IO.File.Exists(currentPath) Then
            '...
        Else
            currentPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "AccountServer.exe")
            '...
        End If
```

Comment: This works awesome, I just couldn't think what code should I use. Thank you!